# For android's navigation drawer, why setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled is required

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

```
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.open_drawer,
                R.string.close_drawer
        );


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

This is part of my code I'm using to set the navigation drawer and the app icon to toggle it.
I'm very confused in that why is it required to `setDrawerListener` when already while constructing the `DrawerToggle` object we have specified the `DrawableLayout` in the constructor.
Second, why is the `setDisplayHomeUpEnabled` required when we are actually not enabling it. And without it, why isn't the ic_drawer displayed?

Thanks.

Comment: For anyone else who too is feeling suffocated because of the convoluted and confusing code for getting basic nav-drawer working can check this https://gist.github.com/emotionull/11087695

Answer (score 1):

From documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html)

> ActionBarDrawerToggle can be used directly as a DrawerLayout.DrawerListener, or if you are already providing your own listener, call through to each of the listener methods from your own.

So `setDrawerListener` method is for setting drawer listener, it could be custom one or you could use your `ActionBarDrawerToggle` object because it already implements `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener`.

Setting `setDisplayHomeUpEnabled` is showing < sign in your action bar but when using navigation drawer it shows three lines.

This is how it is implemented.